# 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, pandas, median

I am trying to find median values in a column of the dataframe. The median value that I am getting is float but I need it in integer format.

```
c_med = round(df['count'].median().astype(int))

c_med = round(df['count'].median()).astype(int)
```

Both the above types give me this error. If `astype(int)` is removed then the answer is correct.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "all_median.py", line 16, in <module>
    c_med = round(df['count'].median()).astype(int)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Comment: What is wrong with `int(data)`?

Comment: You really should go through a tutorial or do more research before posting.  I didnt downvote, but, this question has been answered before.  https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You no longer are in the Pandas API after the `round` function.

You have to cast the value like so

```
c_med = int(round(df['count'].median())
```

I'm not too familiar with Pandas, but you could try

```
c_med = df['count'].median().round().astype(int)
```